# Transforming XML in web service with an xsd on a https server

Tags: java, xml, ssl, glassfish

I have a web service, running on a Linux box, under Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

I'm trying to access an XSLT document:

```
javax.xml.transform.Transformer t =  tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource("https://example.com/my.xsl"));
```

And it worked fine until example.com decided to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Now it fails with:

```
Could not compile stylesheet
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:885)
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:671)
```

My server doesn't trust this certificate, so that's the most probable cause for the problem.

I've installed the website's certificate chain (3 certs) to my server's certificate store (/etc/pki/ca-trust/store/anchors) AND to the relevant domain's keystore.jks store.

However I still get the same error message even though other programs (like wget) can now access the site via https.

Is there any way to ignore the site's certificates (I know, bad practice...) or where should I put them, so my GF web service would work?

Comment: I would rather try to store the xsl locally

Comment: Unfortunately it's a company policy, it has to be ensured that the XSLT is acquired from the remote site every time the program accesses it.

Comment: Can you read the XSL into a stream without error?

Comment: I will try, but it seems that the connection being thru SSL is the problem, I've tried the whole thing with a fake HTTP server (using hosts file to substitute the DNS name to a local server) and via HTTP it still works OK.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to resort to set a periodic job for getting the XSLT outside Java then grabbing the XSLT from a local server via HTTP, faking the local server's name in our DNS to the remote server's name.